# What is the advantage of using DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged for databinding winform c#

Tags: c#, winforms, data-binding

first see my code

```
public class Car : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        private string _make;
        private string _model;
        private int _year;

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        public Car(string make, string model, int year)
        {
            _make = make;
            _model = model;
            _year = year;
        }

        public string Make
        {
            get { return _make; }
            set
            {
                _make = value;
                this.NotifyPropertyChanged("Make");
            }
        }

        public string Model
        {
            get { return _model; }
            set
            {
                _model = value;
                this.NotifyPropertyChanged("Model");
            }
        }

        public int Year
        {
            get { return _year; }
            set
            {
                _year = value;
                this.NotifyPropertyChanged("Year");
            }
        }

        private void NotifyPropertyChanged(string name)
        {
            if (PropertyChanged != null)
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
        }
    }
```

this way i am binding

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        BindingList<Car> ol;

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Car carTest = new Car("Ford", "Mustang", 1967);
            ol = new BindingList<Car>();
            ol.Add(carTest);

            this.textBox1.DataBindings.Add("Text", ol, "Make", true, DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged);
            this.textBox2.DataBindings.Add("Text", ol, "Make", true, DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged);
            this.textBox3.DataBindings.Add("Text", ol, "Make");

            dataGridView1.DataSource = ol;
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            ol.Where(d => d.Make == "Ford").First().Make = "My Ford000";
        }

    }

i use `DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged` for one textbox and did not use for other textbox

this.textBox2.DataBindings.Add("Text", ol, "Make", true, DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged);
this.textBox3.DataBindings.Add("Text", ol, "Make");
```

when change value in one textbox the change is reflected in other textbox too without using `DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged` so just do not understand the advantage of `DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged`

even when change data in data source by the below way then change is also reflected in all textboxes.

```
ol.Where(d => d.Make == "Ford").First().Make = "My Ford000";

please help me to understand right usage of `DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged` like when and where to use.
```

thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you are adding binding in the following way:

```
textBox3.DataBindings.Add("Text", ol, "Make");
```

it uses `DataSourceUpdateMode.OnValidation`, you can check it [here](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Windows.Forms/winforms/Managed/System/WinForms/ControlBindingsCollection.cs,91). So, if you have some validation rules for your control, underlying value won't be updated if validation fails. On the other side `DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged` will update underlying source in any case.

Comment: can u tell me how to write validation routine which will be called validate the data and return true or false for fail or success as u said ?

Comment: one different i noticed that if i bind textbox this way `textBox3.DataBindings.Add("Text", ol, "Make");` so when i made the change then change is not reflected in other textbox untill focus change from that textbox.

Comment: @Mou this is default behavior in WinForms - validation occurs on focus change. You can read this https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229603%28v=vs.110%29.aspx article on validation, just handle the event

Comment: can u give me sample code or redirect me to right article by guide me how to enforce a validation rule for winform controls?

Comment: @Mou I think you can take a look here, for example http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/DipalChoksi/UsingErrorProviderContolinWindowsFormsandCSharp11242005010829AM/UsingErrorProviderContolinWindowsFormsandCSharp.aspx